# What are the four-vector analogues for the geometrical scalar and vector product of two three-vectors?

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors

In Euclidean three-space, we have the usual geometric definitions for the scalar and vector product of two vectors, give by
$\vec A \cdot \vec {B} =|A||B|\cos\theta$ and $A\times B= |A||B|\sin\theta$. Perhaps there's an equivalent for Minkowski-space where $\sin$ and $\cos$ are replaced by $\cosh$ and $\sinh$?

Comment: Start with [due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Descend to two dimensions to see the cross product is a scalar there. So, in four, it should be a 2-tensor---which? Incorporate the metric peculiarity of Minkowski space. Surely, you can do this.

Answer (score 3):

To higher dimensional analog of the scalar product is rather straight forward. In any number of dimensions $A \cdots B = A_1 B_1 + A_2 B_2 + \ldots + A_n B_n$. This is indeed always equal to $A \cdots B = |A||B| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is now the angle between the two vectors in the higher dimensional space.

The four-dimensional analog to the cross product (or vector product) is less straightforward. In three dimensions the cross product takes in two vectors and returns a vector in the direction perpendicular to these two vectors. In a higher number of dimensions there is no longer one unique direction perpendicular to the two input vectors and the operation $A \times B$ becomes ill-defined in that case.

What we can define is the wedge product the Hodge dual of a vector and another vector $\star A \wedge B$. This more complicated operation will in 3-dimensions reduce to our familiar cross product.

The Hodge dual of a vector $\star A = \varepsilon_{ij\ldots n}A^i = A_{j\ldots n}$ is the (n-1)-dimensional hyperplane, perpendicular to that vector. Here $\varepsilon_{ij...n}$ is the fully antisymmetric [Levi-Cevita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). The wedge product is defined as $A \wedge B = A_i B_j\varepsilon^{ij\ldots n}$, so the higher dimensional generalization of the cross product will be $\star A \wedge B = (\epsilon_{ab\ldots n}A^a) \varepsilon^{ib\ldots n} B^i$

When you use the above index notation you can use the above result in both Euclidean and Minkowski spacetime. The only difference is that the $A_0$ component of a vector in Minkowski spacetime is negative.

Comment: Thanks, but please note that by four-vector I meant its usual meaning as a vector in Minkowski space; perhaps this is why someone downvoted your answer which otherwise looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeah I actually upvoted the answer because there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

The Euclidean dot product generalizes to the [Minkowski inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric) $A_\mu B^\mu = {\bf A} \cdot {\bf B} - A^0 B^0$.  There's no single natural way to generalize the cross product, which is unique to three and seven dimensions.  For three-vectors, ${\bf a} \times {\bf b} = {\bf c}$ in components becomes $\epsilon_{ijk} a^i b^j = c_k$, so one can e.g. define a generalized "cross product" between *three* four-vectors via $D_\sigma = \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} A^\mu B^\nu C^\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend your $\theta$ to be the [real-valued] rapidity (arc-length of a unit hyperbola in Minkowski spacetime), then your 4-vectors should be both future-timelike [or both past]. I think it can work with spacelike vectors as long as they are coplanar with the future-timelike vectors, correspondingly orthogonal to the timelike-vectors, and probably must both be in the forward [or backward] spatial direction (so that their unit vectors lie on a common hyperbola... in other words, on a 2D spacetime diagram with those timelike vectors). Then, you can use the hyperbolic trig function of the rapidity.

For the generalization of the cross-product, think of a "bivector".
Its area is related to the $\sinh$-function. In 3D, the Hodge dual (with $\epsilon_{abc}$) would map that to a [pseudo-]vector... not so in 4D (since the $\epsilon_{abcd}$ has four indices).